# Method returns before await finishes executing

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, mudblazor

I am listing data with `Blazor server side` and `MudBlazor`.
I have a user list:

**UserList.razor**

```
public partial class UserList
{
    private async Task<TableData<User>> ServerReload(TableState state)
    {
        var admTableData = await _userService.GetUsersAsTableDataAsync(state.ToAdmTableState());
        return admTableData.ToTableData();
    }
}
```

The service for the user list looks like this:

**UserService.cs**

```
public class UserService
{
    public UserService(MyDbContext myDbContext)
    {
        _userRepository = new UserRepository(myDbContext);
    }

    public Task<AdmTableData<User>> GetUsersAsTableDataAsync(AdmTableState admTableState)
    {
        var queryable = _userRepository.GetUsersAsQueryable();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(admTableState.SearchString))
        {
            queryable = queryable.Where(u => u.Name.Contains(admTableState.SearchString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }

        switch (admTableState.SortLabel)
        {
            case "Name":
                queryable = queryable.OrderByDirection(admTableState.SortDirection, o => o.Name);
                break;
        }

        return PaginationHelper.GetTableDataAsync(queryable, admTableState);
    }
}
```

The `pagination` helper:

**PaginationHelper.cs**

```
public static async Task<AdmTableData<T>> GetTableDataAsync<T>(IQueryable<T> queryable, AdmTableState admTableState)
{
    var admTableData = new AdmTableData<T>();

    admTableData.TotalItems = await queryable.CountAsync();

    admTableData.Items = await queryable.Skip(admTableState.PageNumber * admTableState.PageSize)
        .Take(admTableState.PageSize).ToListAsync();

    return admTableData;
}
```

Lastly. I am registering the `services` in the following way:

**Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("myConnectionString")));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
```

If I order a column. I get this error:

```
Error: System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads concurrently using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.
```

If I do a search. It never gets the data and it keeps loading:

[Loading forever screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjueG.png)

Comment: Are your service/repository singletons, or are they scoped per-request?

Comment: they are scoped per-request

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? If so, how are you passing the DbContext around?

Comment: I add the DbContext by calling the AddDbContext method, then I pass it to the service with dependency injection and then to the repository.

Comment: Hmm okay. This message is caused by a single DbContext instance being used in multiple threads. Can't tell from the code where the problems come from unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `IDbContextFactory` if you are using Blazor server-side, because you can't use the same dbcontext instance multiple times in multiple threads.

Your dbcontext service is scoped, which means it will create a new instance while the new request to the server, but the Blazor server is a single page application and you have a single request and single dbcontext instance, and if you use the same dbcontext like a normal asp.net core application it will give you this error:

```
Error: System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this....
```

You must create dbcontext instances manually. Register your dbcontext like this:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(
     options => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("myConnectionString")));
```

and use it in your code like this:

```
private readonly IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> _contextFactory;

public MyController(IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> contextFactory)
{
    _contextFactory = contextFactory;
}

public void DoSomething()
{
    using (var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext())
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You can read more in [DbContext Lifetime, Configuration, and Initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/).

Comment: Really helpful. I love it.